# Leave padding between strings in the segment

Tags: assembly, mips32, mars-simulator

I'm using mars 4.5 to simulate a mips32.
What I wanted to do is to save strings (.asciiz) not one contiguous with the other, but saving them in a separate places of the memory.  Still near each other, but with a gap.

For example:

```
.data 
string_1: .asciiz  "\nHello, world"
string_2: .asciiz "\n...assembly....\n"
```

In my case `string_1` is saved automatically at address 0x10010000 of the data segment.

I would like `string_2` to be at an address like 0x10010080 for example, instead of right after `string1`.

Can I edit data segment addresses?

Comment: Thank you for corrections Peter and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like GNU as syntax, so I assume MARS just uses gas.

Use [the `.org` directive](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Org.html#Org) to increase the current output position to a given absolute value.  (Read the manual to make sure you understand the restrictions on it, e.g. only within a section, and you can't go backwards.)

```
.data
    string_1: .asciiz  "\nHello, world"
    .org 0x10010080            # fill with zeros until this address
    string_2: .asciiz "\n...assembly....\n"
```

Also note that if you're not going to write the string constants, you should usually put them in `.rodata`.

---

It's more common to just need alignment to some power-of-2 boundary; [use `.p2align`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/P2align.html#P2align) for that.

If you want to pad with a fixed number of bytes, use [`.zero size`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Zero.html).  e.g. `.zero 1234` assembles to 1234 bytes of zeros.